# Vba Download data file only on working days

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, while-loop

I have a problem with correct formatting or method that I should use.

My program:

```
dtReportDateStart = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C2"), "YYYYMMDD")

dtReportDateEnd = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C3"), "YYYYMMDD")

CurrentDate = dtReportDateStart

Do While CurrentDate <> dtReportDateEnd

    Location = "http://." & CurrentDate & ".tsv.txt"

    CurrentDate = CurrentDate + 1
                  
Loop
```

It should take two dates in "YYYYMMDD" format and then work for working days only. Right now it gives an error whenever we have a weekend.  The reason why `CurrentDate` should be in "YYYYMMDD" format is that it downloads values from a data base (Location) which requires exactly that type of formatting.

My ideas:

(1) I printed working days on Dashboard in cells F, starting from F1 and the code could move from cell to cell.

(2) Change data formatting to use WEEKDAY function, `If Weekday(CurrentDate, vbMonday) < 6 Then  [...]`

But in both cases I don't know how to write it

Comment: Add `If Weekday(CurrentDate, vbMonday) < 6 ` into your do loop.  Might be an idea to check the file exists too.  This will help with missing files, but may also handle this error if the file is not produced at weekends?

Comment: It gives an error " type mismatch"

Comment: Try using `dateformat` or `cdate` for your date setting.  WEEKDAY will need a date.

Comment: where to put dateformat() ?

Comment: How did you declare the used variables? Are they `Date` or `Long`?

Comment: they are `String`

Comment: I said when you set your dates or even cdate in the weekday.   Give it more than 1 minte of yoru own effort/research.

Comment: After more than 1 minute of my own effort it return errors in a different area of the code, I saved the files in sheets based on the CurrentDate being a string: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "A_" & CurrentDate` I like this name cause it's easy to follow and it is in the other parts of my code. How to have it working again?

Comment: Becasue `CurrentDate` is now in the format 01/01/2000 and "/" are not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the next function, please:

```
Function isWD(dDbl As Double) As Boolean
     Dim d As Date: d = DateSerial(left(dDbl, 4), Mid(dDbl, 5, 2), Right(dDbl, 2))

     If Weekday(d, vbMonday) < 6 Then isWD = True
End Function
```

Then use it in your code as:

````
Do While CurrentDate <> dtReportDateEnd
  If isWD(CDbl(CurrentDate)) Then
    Location = "http://." & CurrentDate & ".tsv.txt"
  End If
    CurrentDate = CurrentDate + 1                  
Loop ```
````

Comment: Unfortunately it returns an error "ByRef argument type mismatch",  I've got `dtReportdateStart, dtReportDateEnd, CurrentDate` as `string`, where might be the issue?

Comment: @Bob Mac No problem. I will adapt the code to avoid that...

Comment: @Bob Mac Adapted... In my case `TypeName(CurrentDate + 1)` returns `Double`. I forced the call to use the variable as `Double`. Please, test it now.

Comment: I would like to give you an "up" on comment but I have too low reputation

Comment: @Bob Mac No need for that. I do not care to much about reputation. I have enough... I had a target of 2000 but now I achieved more over it... :)

Comment: really great work, I saved it and based on your idea I will tackle other problems